# Find mean of a column for every 1000000 count in R

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I have a dataframe which has the following structure with two columns `data1` and `data2`. Below is the sample data:

```
data1       data2        
800000    1
800030    0.956521739130435
1000000   0.480916030534351
1686626   0.496
1687492   0.174757281553398
2148463   0.0344827586206897
2850823   0.05
2959087   0.0416666666666667
```

I would like to calculate the mean of second row i.e. `data2` for every 1000000 count in `data1`.
which means it should give the mean for first 2 rows then for next 3 rows and then for the next 3 rows and so on...

The output should be a dataframe with last value within the interval 1000000 and the mean value of `data2` in that interval: Sample output is shown below:

```
 800030  0.97826087
 1687492 0.38389110
 2959087 0.04204981
```

Could some help to do this in R?

Comment: Just as a thought: I don't know what you're trying to do, but aren't you trying to calculate a weighted mean? i.e. for the first 1e6 observations, that mean would be (1*0.8e6 + 0.95... *30 + 0.48... *199970) / 1e6. This would be the mean of the first 1e6 counts instead of the mean of the first 3 different results.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your data is in data.frame `DF` , you can use `aggregate` function to do this

```
> with(DF, aggregate(data2, by=list((data1+0.01)%/%1000000), mean ))
  Group.1          x
1       0 0.97826087
2       1 0.38389110
3       2 0.04204981
```

To get the values in column over which `mean` was calculated, you will have to use `aggregate` again - this time on `data1` column itself. After that you can `merge` two resultant dataframes.

```
res <- with(DF, merge(aggregate(data1, by = list((data1 + 0.01)%/%1e+06), paste), aggregate(data2, by = list((data1 + 0.01)%/%1e+06), mean), by = "Group.1"))
names(res) <- c("Group", "Values", "Mean")
res
##   Group                    Values       Mean
## 1     0            800000, 800030 0.97826087
## 2     1 1000000, 1686626, 1687492 0.38389110
## 3     2 2148463, 2850823, 2959087 0.04204981
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want all the values over which the mean was calculated. Only the end value or the maximum value in the interval over which the mean was calculated is required.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this :

```
group <- cut(df$data1, c(0,1000000,2000000,3000000))
tapply(df$data2, group, mean)
# (0,1e+06] (1e+06,2e+06] (2e+06,3e+06] 
# 0.81247926    0.33537864    0.04204981
```

**EDIT :** To automatically compute the `breaks` in `seq`, you can replace `c(0,1000000,2000000,3000000)` with something like :

```
c(seq(0, max(df$data1), by=1000000),max(df$data1))
```

**EDIT 2 :** The following, using `ddply`from `plyr`, will return both mean and max in a data frame :

```
group <- cut(df$data1, c(seq(0, max(df$data1), by=1000000),max(df$data1)))
ddply(df, .(group), summarize, mean=mean(data2), max=max(data2))
#              group       mean   max
# 1        (0,1e+06] 0.81247926 1.000
# 2    (1e+06,2e+06] 0.33537864 0.496
# 3 (2e+06,2.96e+06] 0.04204981 0.050
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is sample data and the original data has many more rows which makes it difficult to group them as you did in line of the code "c(0,1000000,2000000,3000000)".

Comment: Just updated my answer for a way to compute the breaks automatically.

Comment: :This is what exactly i need. The outptu is an array with coordinates from data1 and mean of data2 i.e.(0,1e+06] 0.81247926.Would it be possible to get the maximum value in the interval and the mean value as a dataframe?

Comment: Edited to add max and return a data frame.

Comment: :Not the max value from data2. I need the max value from data1 i.e. from the interval (0,1e+06]. The resultant dataframe should have two vectors one with last coordinate within the interval (0,1e+06] and other with mean value for data2 within the interval.

Comment: I have modified my initial question above, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of diversity, here's another solution using `split`:

```
sapply(split(df,df$data1%/%1e6), function(x)mean(x$data2))
         0          1          2 
0.97826087 0.38389110 0.04204981
```

**Edit**: or even simpler:

```
sapply(split(df$data2,df$data1%/%1e6), mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to propose a solution in the
`tidyverse` universe

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
~data1,   ~data2,        
800000,    1,
800030,    0.956521739130435,
1000000,   0.480916030534351,
1686626,   0.496,
1687492,   0.174757281553398,
2148463,   0.0344827586206897,
2850823,   0.05,
2959087,   0.0416666666666667)

df |> 
  mutate(group= data1 %/% 1000000) |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  summarize(max_in_group = max(data1), mean_data2 = mean(data2), n_in_group = n())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   group max_in_group mean_data2 n_in_group
#>   <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <int>
#> 1     0       800030     0.978           2
#> 2     1      1687492     0.384           3
#> 3     2      2959087     0.0420          3
```

Although it seems not all decimals are printed, it is only an output format
of `dplyr`. All decimals are computed as shown below

```r
df |> 
  mutate(group= data1 %/% 1000000) |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  summarize(max_in_group = max(data1), mean_data2 = mean(data2), n_in_group = n()) |> 
  pull(mean_data2)
#> [1] 0.97826087 0.38389110 0.04204981
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>